# Is there a JS library to display Google Drive contents in a file explorer style view

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

I'm currently using google picker to allow user to choose files from his/her Google Drive. The google picker is an excellent component. It displays all the files in a flat view. This is Ok for most of the time though some users request a file explorer style of file chooser.

Now I was wondering if there is a JS component can display folder/file just like file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/doc) exactly does that, you can use it to select files from Google Drive as well. More implementation details are explained on http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ch/2012/08/allowing-user-to-select-google-drive.html